# Ruby regex split string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, split

Firstly, my knowledge of regex isn't that great. Personally i compare them to Voldemort from the Harry Potter books.

Im trying to split a fairly large string into chunks using regex.

The string is something like(You might want to see it):

```
Hi {{company_name}}\r\n\r\nA new order has been created via your website, from a customer with the following details:\r\n\r\n<table border=\"1\">\r\n  <tr>\r\n    <td>Full Name</td>\r\n    <td>{{ customer.full_name }}</td>\r\n  </tr>\r\n  <tr>\r\n    <td>Email</td>\r\n    <td>{{ customer.email }}</td>\r\n  </tr>\r\n  <tr>\r\n    <td>Mobile</td>\r\n    <td>{{ customer.mobile }}</td>\r\n  </tr>\r\n  <tr>\r\n    <td>Landline</td>\r\n    <td>{{ customer.landline }}</td>\r\n  </tr>\r\n  <tr>\r\n    <td>Notes</td>\r\n    <td>{{ notes }}</td>\r\n  </tr>\r\n</table>\r\n\r\nThese products or services were ordered:\r\n\r\n{% if appointment_items != empty %}\r\nBooking Details\r\n<table border=\"1\">\r\n  <tr>\r\n   <td>Type</td>\r\n   <td>Description</td>\r\n   <td>Price</td>\r\n</tr>\r\n{% for line_item in appointment_items %}\r\n<tr>\r\n  <td>{{ line_item.category }}</td>\r\n  <td>{{ line_item.short_description}}</td>\r\n  <td>{{ line_item.price | display_price }}</td>\r\n</tr>\r\n{% endfor %}\r\n</table>\r\n{% endif %}\r\n\r\n{% if enquiry_items != empty %}\r\nEnquiry Details\r\n<table border=\"1\">\r\n  <tr>\r\n   <td>Type</td>\r\n   <td>Description</td>\r\n   <td>Price</td>\r\n</tr>\r\n{% for line_item in enquiry_items %}\r\n<tr>\r\n  <td>{{ line_item.category }}</td>\r\n  <td>{{ line_item.short_description}}</td>\r\n  <td>{{ line_item.price | display_price }}</td>\r\n</tr>\r\n{% endfor %}\r\n</table>\r\n{% endif %}\r\n\r\n{% if has_appointment %}\r\n\r\nOne or more of the order items requires an engineer appointment. This appointment has been allocated to an engineer and given a provisional appointment time.\r\n\r\n<table border=\"1\">\r\n  <tr>\r\n    <td>Start</td>\r\n    <td>{{ appointment.start | date_with_time_zone: \"%A %d %b %Y at %H:%M %P\"  }}</td>\r\n  </tr>\r\n  <tr>\r\n    <td>Finish</td>\r\n    <td>{{ appointment.finish | date_with_time_zone: \"%A %d %b %Y at %H:%M %P\"  }}</td>\r\n  </tr>\r\n  <tr>\r\n    <td>Duration</td>\r\n    <td>{{ appointment.duration }}</td>\r\n  </tr>\r\n  <tr>\r\n    <td>Engineer Name</td>\r\n    <td>{{ appointment.engineer }}</td>\r\n  </tr>\r\n</table>\r\n\r\nThe address of the appointment is:\r\n\r\n<table border=\"1\">\r\n  <tr>\r\n    <td>Address Line 1</td>\r\n    <td>{{ appointment.address.line_one }}</td>\r\n  </tr>\r\n  <tr>\r\n    <td>Address Line 2</td>\r\n    <td>{{ appointment.address.line_two }}</td>\r\n  </tr>\r\n  <tr>\r\n    <td>Town/City</td>\r\n    <td>{{ appointment.address.town_city }}</td>\r\n  </tr>\r\n  <tr>\r\n    <td>County</td>\r\n    <td>{{ appointment.address.county }}</td>\r\n  </tr>\r\n  <tr>\r\n    <td>Postcode</td>\r\n    <td>{{ appointment.address.postcode }}</td>\r\n  </tr>\r\n</table>\{% endif %}
```

So this string is an email that is stored in the database then parsed using liquid tags.

Liquid is a tempting language. It has the notion of variables like: `{{ var_name }}` and logic such as if statements like: `{% if var_name == true %} //do something {% endif %}`

I need to be able to get the longest string that is 100% going to be in this email when it is sent out. My final goal is writing a test that checks the body of the email for the longest string.

I came up with this:

```
regex = /{{.*?}}|\\\n|\\\r|({%\s?if).*(endif\s?%})/

mail_template_content_part = @mail_template.content.split(regex).reject(&:empty?).map(&:strip).max_by(&:length)
```

regex *should* be splitting on liquid vars `{{ my_var }}` new lines, and on the opening of an `{% if` and everything up to a close `endif %}`

I love the `max_by` method :D

Now each of the options work individually. But when the are all put together they don't seem to work. I'm not sure whats going on, my suspicion is that the split is splitting as it goes thus the if/end part of the regex is not running.

So my question(s) are

What is wrong with the regex?

How does a split work with regex?

Am I going about this the right way?

Thanks,

Dickie

Comment: Don't specify new-lines and carriage-returns like `\\\n|\\\r`. Use `[\r\n]+`.

Comment: By "splitting on..." do you mean you want `{{vars}}`, new-lines and conditionals in their own array elements?

Comment: For future questions, please reduce the sample data to the *minimum* needed to reproduce the problem. Anything else beyond that is a waste of space, of our time as we "parse" it as we read, and tends to discourage responses because people answering are doing on their own time as volunteers.

Answer (score 0):

Hmhmmm, using regular expressions to parse languages is just a crutch....

Liquid itself uses tons of regular expressions never the less. They recently changed it to use a real parser though.

I was thinking that it might be a better idea to annotate the part that should go into the email with a custom Liquid tag or a custom HTML tag, id or class.

Comment: No can do I'm afraid the emails are designed to be edited through a CMS. Thus i cannot guarantee that something will be there.